# How to keep running a program on Linux through SSH connection?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ssh

I connect to linux server through ssh like:

```
ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

filled password,then I run a long-running program such as:

```
java -jar abc.jar -Dserver.port=80
```

but when I close the ssh connection on my computer,the program running on linux server is closed too.How can I keep the program running after close the ssh connection?

Comment: On the server, use something like "nohup", "disown"  or "screen".  https://askubuntu.com/questions/600956/alternatives-to-nohup

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using nohup. Prefixing your command with nohup prevents the command from being aborted if you log out or exit the shell.

```
nohup java -jar abc.jar -Dserver.port=80 &
```

This seems to be the simplest method to achieve this.

Comment: yes it works,thanks.but if I want to see the program's logs or shut down the program after close the bash ,how can I do this?